# Exporting kineticJS to image (datatoURL)

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I ran into an issue while using kineticJS to create multiple stages.

I am trying to export multiple "stages" to images but I cant get past exporting the first stage, the datatoURL function doesnt seem to be working, and it breaks my script, or perhaps I'm calling it at the wrong location...
When the user clicks the save button, each stage should be converted to an image and displayed on the same page.

Can anyone tell me why the first stage is not being displayed as an image on the page?

Thanks in advance

Here is the code that puts the stage data into the image placeholder on the page.

```
            document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
            stage.toDataURL({
            callback: function(dataUrl) {
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataUrl;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
            }
            });
            }, false);
```

below is the full code:

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Canvas</title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(window).load(function(){
            var highlightWidth = 8;

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container1',
            width: 300,
            height: 100
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);



            document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
            stage.toDataURL({
            callback: function(dataUrl) {
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataUrl;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
            }
            });
            }, false);



            var dropzone = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container2',
            width: 300,
            height: 100
            });
            var dropLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            dropzone.add(dropLayer);


            addBackground(stage, layer, dropLayer);
            layer.draw();
            addBackground(dropzone, dropLayer, layer);
            dropLayer.draw();





            var stage2 = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container3',
            width: 300,
            height: 100
            });
            var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
            stage2.add(layer2);


            var dropzone2 = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container4',
            width: 300,
            height: 100
            });
            var dropLayer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
            dropzone2.add(dropLayer2);



            addBackground(stage2, layer2, dropLayer2);
            layer2.draw();
            addBackground(dropzone2, dropLayer2, layer2);
            dropLayer2.draw();

            var images = {};
            var URLs = {
            house1: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-3.jpg',
            house2: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-4.jpg',
            house3: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-1.jpg'
            };
            loadImages(URLs, start);


            function start() {
            var house1 = kImage(images.house1, 10, 10, 50, 50, layer);
            var house2 = kImage(images.house2, 75, 10, 50, 50, layer);
            var house3 = kImage(images.house3, 140, 10, 50, 50, layer);
            layer.draw();
            var house1 = kImage(images.house1, 10, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer);
            var house2 = kImage(images.house2, 75, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer);
            var house3 = kImage(images.house3, 140, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer);
            dropLayer.draw();
            var house1 = kImage(images.house1, 10, 10, 50, 50, layer2);
            var house2 = kImage(images.house2, 75, 10, 50, 50, layer2);
            var house3 = kImage(images.house3, 140, 10, 50, 50, layer2);
            layer.draw();
            var house1 = kImage(images.house1, 10, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer2);
            var house2 = kImage(images.house2, 75, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer2);
            var house3 = kImage(images.house3, 140, 10, 50, 50, dropLayer2);
            dropLayer.draw();
            }

            function swapStagesIfSelected(sourceLayer, destinationLayer, startX, startY) {


            var elements = sourceLayer.get("Image");


            var totalWidth = 0;
            var maxHeight = -999;
            var layerWidth = destinationLayer.getStage().getWidth();
            var layerHeight = destinationLayer.getStage().getHeight();
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].isSelected) {
            totalWidth += elements[i].getWidth();
            maxHeight = Math.max(elements[i].getHeight(), maxHeight);
            }
            }
            if (startX + totalWidth > layerWidth) {
            startX = layerWidth - totalWidth - 15;
            }
            if (startY + maxHeight > layerHeight) {
            startY = layerHeight - maxHeight - 15;
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            if (element.isSelected) {
            var img = element.getImage();
            kImage(img, startX, startY, element.getWidth(), element.getHeight(), destinationLayer);
            startX += element.getWidth() + 10;
            element.remove();
            }
            }
            sourceLayer.draw();
            destinationLayer.draw();
            }


            function kImage(image, x, y, width, height, theLayer) {
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: image,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            stroke: "white",
            draggable: true
            });
            image.myLayer = theLayer;
            image.isSelected = false;
            image.on("click", function () {

            this.myLayer.draw();
            });
            image.myLayer.add(image);
            return (image);
            }


            function addBackground(theStage, theLayer, otherLayer) {

            var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: theStage.getWidth(),
            height: theStage.getHeight(),
            fill: "white",
            stroke: "blue",
            strokeWidth: 1
            });
            background.on("click", function () {
            var pos = theStage.getMousePosition();
            var mouseX = parseInt(pos.x);
            var mouseY = parseInt(pos.y);
            swapStagesIfSelected(otherLayer, theLayer, mouseX, mouseY);
            });
            theLayer.add(background);
            }


            function loadImages(URLs, callback) {
            var loaded = 0;
            var needed = 0;
            for (var url in URLs) {
            needed++;
            console.log(url);
            }
            for (var url in URLs) {
            images[url] = new Image();
            images[url].onload = function () {
            if (++loaded >= needed) {
            callback(images);
            }
            };
            images[url].src = URLs[url];
            }
            }
            });
            </script>

            </head>
            <body>

            <div id="container1"></div>
            <div id="container2"></div>
            <div id="container3"></div>
            <div id="container4"></div>

            <img style="background:url(test1.png);" id="canvasimg"  style="display:none;">

            <button id="save">Save as image</button>


            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: Use Dev Tools to check the error. I would say the the error is cross domain restriction. toDataURL will not allow you to convert images from another domain. So if your page is at  myDomain.com and the images are from anotherDomain.com then you can not use toDataURL. To solve this problem move the images you wish to use to your server so that they are from the same domain as your page.